# Should retain name filter on users page

Tags: feature-request, users-page

When clicking between "Week", "Month", "Quarter", "Year" and "All" on the users page, the name I have typed in to filter on disappears. I feel like it should stay there, so that I can type in my name, and see how I've done in a week/month/etc.

Comment: I agree.  For some reason, I had believed that clicking “Month” would keep the name filter until I actually clicked it, which surprisingly reset the name filter.

Answer (score 2):

This is not only with the name filter:

If you click on the "Week" tab for instance, you go to this url:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week

but there the "next page" button doesn't include that filter:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation

so when you click it, you're back to the default "month" filter.

Answer (score -4):

This is exactly what the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) already do.  On every page, it shows *your* place at the very top.  Preferable to use the feature that was actually designed explicitly for this purpose, no?

Comment: Preferable perhaps, yes... but if it confuses the user, should it not be corrected anyway?

Comment: @Smashery: What, precisely, is confusing about this?  On what other web pages are the values of form elements preserved when you navigate to different web pages?  Your stated use case (checking your rank) is already handled effectively by an existing feature, so unless there is another use case you neglected to mention, there seems to be no benefit to this.

Comment: All I'm really saying is that from a sample size of me, I was confused that when I filtered down and didn't see that filter retained. Perhaps you would not expect that behaviour; I am reporting that I did expect that behaviour.

Comment: As to what other web pages retain form elements when navigating between: conceptually, I don't see this as a form - I conceptualise it as two filters: one by name, one by time period, giving me the data that passes through both filters. And most, if not all, filters I've ever used, will retain the rest of the filter information when updating one part of the it. Like I say, this is just my experience - I expected different behaviour.

Comment: -1 because this answer only addresses the case where you're typing your own name in; I encountered this earlier today while searching for someone else, and I can't use the rep league for that. Well, not easily, anyways.