# Can we preserve the search textbox's value while moving between tabs?

Tags: feature-request, tabs, users-page

When we visit this page user's page https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation , If you write any user's name and then move another tag suppose from `reputation` to `new user` then it is clearing the textbox's previous value.

> [image]

`Abra ka dabra` Search Textbox is blank when you switch the tab.

> [image]

If I want to search then again I need to write down user's name . Can we change this to preserve the search textbox's value while moving between tabs of `reputation`,`new users`,`votes`,`editors`,`moderatos` ?

Comment: I just check that word "preservation" is working find for the [linked duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81287/247179) but it is not working for the tab I mentioned in my question. So can we reopen this question ?